# How to add a statement to actionPerformed to call a LinkedList and to store the result in a new variable

Tags: java, arrays, list, linked-list, gettext

How to add a statement to actionPerformed to call mkList and to store the result in a new variable LinkedList aList.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {    
    if (event.getSource() == reading) {
        String s = txt1.getText();
        String delims = expression.getText(); 
        String[] anArray = s.split(delims);
        result.setText("");
        print(anArray);
    } 
    LinkedList<String> mkList;
    LinkedList<String> aList = new LinkedList<String>();

} // actionPerformed

public LinkedList<String> mkList(String[] sa) {
    LinkedList<String> st = new LinkedList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sa.length && sa[i] != null; i++)
    st.add(sa[i] + "\n");
    return st;
} // mkList
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make `anArray` variable  **local variable** so that you can use it to pass it as an argument to `mkList()` method outside `if statement`.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {    
String[] anArray=null;  
  if (event.getSource() == reading) {
        String s = txt1.getText();
        String delims = expression.getText(); 
        anArray = s.split(delims);
        result.setText("");
        print(anArray);
    } 
    LinkedList<String> mkList;
    LinkedList<String> aList = new LinkedList<String>();
    if(anArray!=null)        
     aList = mkList(anArray);

} // actionPerformed
```